# Using eclipse resource filters

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to manage few Java files inside a huge project. I want filter all unnecessary files ( project folder -> properties -> resource -> resource filters ) to optimize my setting (Eclipse hangs often).

I need just two folders ( and the subfolders ) at the project root:

- `src/java`
- `test/java`

I tried it with *Include Only* and *Name*, *Location*, *Project Relative Path* that should matches e.g. `src/java/*`, but there was no way to get only these two folders as resources.

Answer (score 2):

Resource Filters will filter the artifacts during your build. But if you want only specific files or folders **that are part of your project**, then you need to create a **Working Set**. What's more handy is that you can even choose to build only these set of files instead of the whole project thereby reducing build time by re-compiling only the modified files.

Refer [Eclipse Working Sets Explained](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-working-sets-explained) on how to create and build working sets.

NOTE: You may use **Resource** when selecting the type.

Update:

**To CREATE a working set:**

- Click on the down arrow located at the top-right
- Click *Select Working Set*
- Click *New* to create your working set

**To MANAGE / EDIT a working set:**
Use the Edit.. button instead of the *New* button as mentioned above

**To SELECT / BUILD a working set:**
Use the corresponding option in the *Project* menu

Hope this helps...

Comment: I can't follow the instructions for filtering cause i can't find any _Manage working set_ or the shown _Edit working set_ dialog. I use Eclipse 3.7.2.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm "Resource filters allow you to configure which files and folders are included automatically in a project resource hierarchy when refresh is performed. "

Answer (score 1):

Trying to include only the required directory doesn't seem to work at nested level. What works is to exclude everything else other than required directory.

So in Edit Resource Filter Dialog choose

- Exclude all
- then Applies to - Folders
- then check - All children(recursive)
- then under FilterDetails choose "Project Rleate Path" and "matches" and check "Regular Expression"
- Now for the case where you want to only include directory java under src, you should use the expression:
  `src/(?!java).*`

So now everything except the directory java under src should be gone.

If you need more than one directory under src then you could try with '|' in the expression field.

Comment: Although it looks promising, this is not working for me. I wonder if it's because I'm trying to apply to Resource Filter to a _linked folder_ within a _virtual folder_.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Explorer View > Click on View Menu (Will be on the top- something like a down arrow ) > Customize View . It will show filter, in that you choose to hide all the non-java elements etc.

Comment: Thanks. Easy solution but there are also other folders (with xml files) i did not mentioned to simplyfy my questions. :-)